# imshow() function in opencv not working on the windows

Tags: python, opencv, imshow, issue-tracking

When I use the imshow() function after reading the image.I am getting this error :

```
OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:627: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

I have unistalled and installed the opencv library severeal times but I am unable to resolve this issue.

I installed the opencv using pip install opencv-python

I would be very grateful if someone can guide me in this regard. Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Try you using this `cv2.waitKey(0);cv2.destroyAllWindows()` after `cv2.imshow(...)`

Comment: Please provide a [mre], show your actual code and the whole error message including the stacktrace. How did you install OpenCV, what's your development environment?

Comment: import cv2 img = cv2.imread("pic.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 
print(img) 
if img is None: print("Object does not exist") 
else: cv2.imshow('firstImg', img) 
cv2.waitKey() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

This is a very basic code just to check if the libraries are working however, it shows the above error. Yes I also tried to install it with the same command you mentioned but it is not working

Comment: how did you install opencv?

Comment: using pip. this command : pip install opencv-python

Answer (score -1):

Install the below package along with opencv-python

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: import cv2 img = cv2.imread("pic.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) print(img) if img is None: print("Object does not exist") else: cv2.imshow('firstImg', img) cv2.waitKey() cv2.destroyAllWindows() This is a very basic code just to check if the libraries are working however, it shows the above error. Yes I also tried to install it with the same command you mentioned but it is not working

Comment: I used your code as well but the same error is coming again and again is there any kind of bug in the opencv library. Forexample, if I read the image, it is stored but if I want to show that image by using imshow, it gives the error.

Comment: @SalahuddinKurd install this package also   

```pip install opencv-contrib-python```

Comment: AayushGupta I did that too but to no affect.